# Get the position of a user after points have been calculated

Tags: mysql

I trying to get the position of a user after the points have been added. So far I have got the following  working properly:

```
SELECT 
    u.userID
,   u.username 
,   SUM(fp.finishingPositionPoints) AS totalPoints

FROM leagueinformation li

INNER JOIN users u ON  u.userID = li.userID
INNER JOIN finishingPosition fp ON  fp.finishingPositionID = li.finishingPositionID

WHERE li.leagueID='1'

GROUP BY li.userID
ORDER BY totalPoints DESC
```

The above code produces something like this:

---

```
userID | username | points

--------

1      |   user1  |  150


2      |   user2  |  127

3      |   user3  |  100

-------------------------
```

From the above example how would I then get the second user position (e.g. second place) ?

Comment: Add `LIMIT 1,1` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this to get the second data ie, add `LIMIT 1,1`

```
SELECT 
    u.userID
,   u.username 
,   SUM(fp.finishingPositionPoints) AS totalPoints

FROM leagueinformation li

INNER JOIN users u ON  u.userID = li.userID
INNER JOIN finishingPosition fp ON  fp.finishingPositionID = li.finishingPositionID

WHERE li.leagueID='1'

GROUP BY li.userID
ORDER BY totalPoints DESC
LIMIT 1, 1 --selects only second item
```

Comment: That works for the above example, however, how could make it dynamic so this works for different userID's? So when someone logins they get their positions for each league they are current entered into?